# PHP: htmlspecialchars, but keep HTML entities

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I've been working on a small side project which formats Skype logs to make them look nice. This is going great, but I have hit a somewhat annoying bump in the road.

[Here](http://chatformat.com/new/viewnew.php?id=70) is a great (and somewhat obscene) example of what is going on. As you can see, htmlspecialchars() also converts HTML character codes into a string (because `&` becomes `&amp;`). I was wondering if there was a way to allow HTML entities to still remain through htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Decode your HTML into text (i.e. `&amp;` becomes `&`) and then escape it when printing.

Comment: Isn't that the function of htmlspecialchars?

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) already provides an option called `$double_encode` (among other flags) to avoid reencoding.

Comment: @mario: You don't do the first step, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlentities() if it solve your problems, else store the string in one variable which returns from the functions and then while printing that string

```
$foo = str_replace("&amp;","&","$bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this function:**

```
$string=$_POST[pname];
function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace('&',' ',$string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
$sclean=seoUrl($string);
```

You can use `str_replace('&',' ',$string);` *instead of `&` use what character you want remove*...